All points are not reflected on the map in R
I have data with 209 FEATURES points like this in R.
> demo
Simple feature collection with 209 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 129.9662 ymin: 31.71758 xmax: 131.6275 ymax: 33.8741
Geodetic CRS:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
# A tibble: 209 × 4
   osm_id     name  `name:en`                geom
 * <chr>      <chr> <chr>             <POINT [°]>
 1 1030679209 NA    NA        (130.7952 33.86543)
 2 1036677582 NA    NA        (130.7951 33.86552)
 3 1036677615 NA    NA        (130.7948 33.86554)
 4 1036677647 NA    NA         (130.795 33.86528)
 5 1036677676 NA    NA        (130.7951 33.86558)
 6 1036677700 NA    NA         (130.7949 33.8656)
 7 1036677710 NA    NA         (130.7948 33.8654)
 8 1036677798 NA    NA        (130.7951 33.86531)
 9 1292353158 NA    NA         (130.2694 31.7179)
10 1292356264 NA    NA        (130.2693 31.71761)
# ℹ 199 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

I use this data to display on maps in the leaflet package.
demo2 <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircles(data = demo, 
              radius = 2,
              color = "black",
              fillColor = "blue")

However, only 10 points are shown on the map.
I have tried everything but cannot solve this error.
Please let me know if you know how to solve this problem.

Could you share a sample of the data with dput() so we can copy/paste it and use it? I'm not sure if head works on features objects but maybe dput(head(demo, 15)) for the first 15 rows. And also would you share a screenshot of your map so we can see what you're seeing?

Please (always!) provide the libraries in use.  Where are leaflet and addTiles etc. to be found?

Peeking at your first few rows,  I suspect your  radius of "2" is causing almost all your points to overlap.  Pay close attention to the plotted positions, and, as always, start by plotting one point, add another, etc.,  maybe with a different color each time, to see where your data are being plotted.

To the point @CarlWitthoft is making, you can check to see if the points are really there but hidden because they overlap by changing addCircles() to addCircleMarkers() and then adding the argument clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(). This will combine your circles into a cluster (based on zoom level) while displaying the total number of points represented by each cluster. If the issue is just overlapping circles, then those totals should sum to 209.
